# LDAP ACL to restrict user to only reading their own user attrs

Tags: ldap, openldap

I want to prevent users from accessing anything other than their own data.

I've tried implementing the following simple acl (ldif):

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by self read by * none
olcAccess: {2}to * by self read by * none
```

When I apply this ldif, I am no longer to query `(objectClass=posixAccount)`. If I change the last acl to `to * by * read`, the query returns all users.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that in order to access a record, one must have "search" privilege. I changed the ACL to:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by self read by * none
olcAccess: {2}to * by self read by * search
```

Using that I was able to query `(objectClass=posixAccount)` without showing other accounts.